# List Confusion in python

Tags: python

The code is:

```
class MyClass:
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        ...
    def __delitem__(self, index):
        ...

    if sys.version_info < (2, 0):
        # They won't be defined if version is at least 2.0 final

        def __getslice__(self, i, j):
            return self[max(0, i):max(0, j):]
        def __setslice__(self, i, j, seq):
            self[max(0, i):max(0, j):] = seq
        def __delslice__(self, i, j):
            del self[max(0, i):max(0, j):]
```

I just didn't get what `__getslice__(self,i,j)`, `__setslice__(self,i,j,seq)` and `__delslice__(self,i,j)` returns.

Are they returning a list here? If not please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__getslice__` is the implementation for yourobj[a:b:c] and, althought it's deprecated, you can still implement it. `__setslice__` and `__delslice__` are deprecated as well, and are the setter and deleter for `__getslice__`.

What does that method return? See your code: `__getslice__` is being implemented only of python < 2.0 (i.e. only when their implementation need is not deprecated).

`__getslice__` returns self[max(i,0),max(j,0)] which would call `__getslice__` again in python < 2.0.  I think it'll give you a Stack Overflow (you're calling it on `self`, which in turn will call the same method again).

Let's see (python < 2.0):
  `__getslice__`(-4, 2) will return self[0, 2], which will be transformed in `__getslice__`(0, 2), which will return self[0, 2], which will become a call to `__getslice__`(0, 2) and so in an infinite fashion (or until your memory stack explodes).

Comment: so here in max(0,1) the maximum is fetched suppose its i and from max (o,j) j is fetched so it will form a slice like [i:j] ..Am i right ?

Comment: yes, it's like that. max(0, i) returns the max between 0 and i. it means: "if i is negative, return 0. otherwise return i". the analogous for max(0, j). But with the code as you have it, test it with a < 2.0 python version, since it could produce an endless loop or stack overflow (python > 2.0 doesn't use `__getslice__` for custom classes)

Answer (score 0):

Btw., **`__getslice__`** is deprecated, although still used http://bugs.python.org/issue2041

The code you pasted only defines these functions for **very very old version** of Python interpreter.

Anyhow if you want to implement these functions, follow what any builtin type, e.g. `list` does:

**`__setslice__`**  doesn't return anything, but replaces own range `(i, j)` with content of `seq`

```
In [3]: l = list()

In [4]: l.__setslice__(1, 3, [1,2,3])

In [5]: l
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3]
```

**`__delslice__`** doesn't return anything, removes own range `(i, j)`

**`__getslice__`** returns own elements in range `(i, j)`

```
In [10]: l = range(5)

In [11]: l.__getslice__(1,3)
Out[11]: [1, 2]

In [12]: l[1:2]
Out[12]: [1]

In [13]: l[1:2+1]
Out[13]: [1, 2]
```

Of course you are free to implement these methods to do whatever you like and return whatever you like, but it's better to keep with the expected semantics.

Finally Python has a **`slice` builtin**, which is a container for index, `i, j, step`, for example:

```
In [18]: l[s]
Out[18]: [1, 3]

In [19]: l = range(100)

In [20]: s = slice(1, 10, 2)

In [21]: l[s]
Out[21]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

In [22]: l[1:10:2]
Out[22]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: actually according to the code its returning a slice right ?

Comment: It returns "a slice of self", as in a sequence of elements contained in `self` starting from `i'th` element and ending on `j'th` element. Python also has (or used to have) a `slice` builtin, which is a container for index expressions, but doesn't hold actual data, I'll update answer with example.

Comment: so here in max(0,1) the maximum is fetched suppose its i and from max (o,j) j is fetched so it will form a slice like [i:j] ..Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

As with most of python's hook methods, `__getslice__` can return pretty much anything you want it to.  `__setslice__` and `__delslice__` shouldn't return anything.

Note that the usage of these methods is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) -- You shouldn't actually need to use them  *unless* you're actually subclassing a python builtin which still implements that method (or another user defined class which implements those methods I suppose).

Comment: actually according to the code its returning a slice  right ??

Comment: @user3501595 -- No.  In the code provided, you'll probably find yourself with a recursion error.  `__getslice__` calls `self[max(0, i):max(0, j):]` which is mapped to `__getslice__` which calls `self[max(0, i):max(0, j):]` which is mapped to `__getslice__` ...

Comment: so here in max(0,1) the maximum is fetched suppose its i and from max (o,j) j is fetched so it will form a slice like [i:j] ..Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

In pre-2.0 version of Python, slices were handled separately from indices. `seq[i]` would invoke `seq.__getitem__(i)`, while `seq[i:j]` would invoke `seq.__getslice__(i,j)`. Since 2.0, however, `__getitem__` handles both cases by receiving a single slice object as its argument, that is, `seq[i:j]` invokes `seq.__getitem__(slice(i,j))` instead. They are essentially unnecessary unless you need to override them when subclassing a built-in type with the CPython implementation.

In your code, `__getslice__` returns whatever `__getitem__` returns, while `__setslice__` and `__delslice__` each return `None`.

Comment: so here in max(0,1) the maximum is fetched suppose its i and from max (o,j) j is fetched so it will form a slice like [i:j] ..Am i right ?